# Simple Program to check whether input String is a keyword or not (keywords are specified)

Tags: java, if-statement

This is the code I'm trying to execute but I get the same result no matter what the input is, i.e. "<input string> is not a keyword".

Here is the list of keywords: {break, case, continue, default, defer, else, for, func, goto, if, map, range, return, struct, type, var}

I want to print **"<input string> is a keyword"** if my input string is present in the list of keywords; else print **"<input string> is not a keyword"**.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package word.is.key;

/**
 *
 * @author JagritSharma
 */
import java.util.*;
public class WordIsKey {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Scanner input= new Scanner(System.in);
        String s= "break, case, continue, default, defer, else, for, func, goto, if, map, range, return, struct, type, var";
        String[] keywords= s.split(",", 16);
        String n= input.nextLine();
        String res= n+" is not a keyword";
        for(int i=0;i<keywords.length;i++){
            if(keywords[i].equals(n)){
                res= n+" is a keyword";
                break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println(res);
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Try splitting on `", "` rather than `","`. Python doesn't remove the spaces automatically, you have to do it yourself.

Comment: You can also remove spaces at the beginning and end with the trim() function. a simple `keywords[i].trim().equals(n)` should make your code work as expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when you split `"break, case"` on `","` you will get the strings `"break"` and `" case"`. Your code therefore only works for the first keyword `break` since all other keywords have the extra space.
You need to either split on `", "` or choose another method to remove the extra space before comparing them with your input i.e. `keywords[i].trim().equals(n)`.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is remove spaces from your input string of keywords i.e. make it as "default,case,break" instead of "default, case, break".

When you are splitting the string into an array, it is splitting on commas and appending the preceding space before the next element to the element itself. Thus your "case" is being taken as " case".

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to turn a string representation of a list of keywords into an array of keywords, why not just initialize the array of keywords directly:

```
    String[] keywords= {
        "break", "case", "continue", "default",
        "defer", "else", "for", "func", "goto", 
        "if", "map", "range", "return", "struct", 
        "type", "var"};
```

Comment: The string was given in the question

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above just use:

```
javax.lang.model.SourceVersion.isName( keyWord );
```

That way you will always have the latest list of keywords for the version you are using.